# Randomly pick a line and save each word on that line into each Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, text

pick a line depending on variable "number"
then save each of the words on that line into each javascript variable1 and javascript variable2.

if variable number equals 2, pick line 2, set Variables1 to potato ,and set Variables2 to tomato.

```
//Text file on server 

Apple, Oranges
Potato, Tomato
Cake, Muffin
Cheese, Milk



//Java script code in browser. 
    var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET","http://..........data.txt",false);
    xhr.send(null);
```

What should I do next?

Any help is appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the issue with your current code?

Comment: updated question, randomly pick a line, then set each of the word on the same line into different variables. but my code sets all words in text file to each variable.

Comment: updated question, simplified requirements

Answer (score 0):

You better off chosing random string via your backend server rather than js because servers meant to do that. You could create a page to which you will reffer to and pass path to your file as parameter and set it to return random line from that file. After you parsed that string you can use `split()` onto your parsed string to get an array of those words. Also you should consider using `fetch` 'cause it's a replacement for a `XHR`.

So my `js` code looks something like this:

```
function getTextFile(path){
    var line = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    params = {
        path: path,
        line: line
    }

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("json", JSON.stringify(params));

    var promise = fetch("http://mysite/myscript.php", {method: 'POST', body: data})
    .then((response) => {
        return response.text();
    }).then((text) => {
        if(text != 'error'){
           text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
           var result = text.split(" ");
           //Result will be an array of those values and will look something   like that:
           //["Cheese", "Milk", "Yogurt"]
        }
        else{
           alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

And then on a backend it looks like that:

```
$json = (array) json_decode($_POST['json']);


if( validatePath($json['path']) ){
    $file = file($json['path']);
    $my_string = $file[$json['line']];
    echo $my_string;
}
else{
    echo 'error';
}


function validatePath($path){
    //You should definitely use some other validations
    $allowedExtensions = ['txt', 'json'];
    $pathinfo = pathinfo($path);
    //Right now it's only checking for right extension and 
    //that's this file ain't located in admin subdir
    if(strstr($pathino['dirname'], '/admin') || !in_array($pathinfo['extension'], $allowedExtensions)){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        //Check if file exists
        if( file_exists($path) ){
            return true;    
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Although not every browser supports `fetch` and if you want to support more browsers you'll need polyfill.

Comment: simplified my requirements, I used var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);  for picking the line.   Do you know how I should use php on server to achive my goal? Thanks